# Delayed job joining

Tags: interviewing

I recently applied for a job and am close to getting an offer. The issue is that my current contract runs till june 2015 and during the HR interview phase I said that I could be available early 2015. If I do get the job offer, how do I get them to let me join in June rather than Jan//Feb 2015?

Comment: It sounds like you lied to HR about when you would be available.  Why did you do that?

Comment: I was thinking that I might be able to get someone to fill my current role. however, that does not seem likely now. While it does sound like a lie, I am truly interested in the job. Not sure if I should make let them know before they give me a final offer

Comment: Do you have a notice period with your current job?

Comment: Be honest, and do it as soon as possible! If you won't be available by the time you stated, just tell them why you can't and when you'll be available.

Comment: @Bernhard, I have a 2 week notice period. If possible, I would prefer to serve out the contract though

Comment: @user308827 Why? Better keep your new employer happy than your current employer. At least without more information.

Comment: @Bernhard, true that, I really do not want to burn any bridges with my previous employer though. I got that job through a mentor I have a lot of respect for.

Comment: Contact the new employer and give them an accurate availability date. If that means you lose the offer, well, that's why you don't want to give bad info during the interview.

Comment: What sort of a contract?  If it's the sort of contract where they can fire you at any time, then you are equally free to leave at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue is that my current contract runs till june 2015 and during
>   the HR interview phase I said that I could be available early 2015. If
>   I do get the job offer, how do I get them to let me join in June
>   rather than Jan//Feb 2015?
>
> I was thinking that I might be able to get someone to fill my current
>   role. however, that does not seem likely now. While it does sound like
>   a lie, I am truly interested in the job.

If you actually do get an offer, you will need to immediately explain that you were hoping to have your current role filled so that you could join in January, but that it hasn't worked out.

You will need to apologize, and ask if it is possible to delay your arrival until June.

Expect the answer to be "No". Most companies hire for positions of immediate need, not 6 months out. But you'll only know for sure if you ask.

Comment: thanks @Joe, as you said, their answer will probably be no; in which case, I just want to make sure that I am not blacklisted and able to reapply if the opportunity arises again.